# Simple way to give this image a more 3-D effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

[image]

Newbie to photoshop. 
Any ideas on how to give this image a more 3-D effect? The purpose of the diamond is for art for a game.

Comment: What's wrong with it? What effect are you trying to achieve and what have you tried? Right now the question is a bit too broad to answer, please try to narrow the scope down a bit.

Comment: The image seems too flat, I want it to have a more 3D effect. Like a diamond?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you want to achieve. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Answer (score 9):

Diamonds are fragmented as prisms. If you want it to appear more 3D you need to find a way to make it appear fragmented. This could be with lines such as:

[image]

Or through gradients and shading like this:

[image]

Yours looks flat because it is. The entire front is just one piece. You need to add lines and/or shading to create depth to it showing where different fragments are.